# object keys values are undefined even though they are truthy

Tags: javascript, object

I want to check if the persona objects are falsy or truthy and depending on that log the values of the object keys into the console or displaying an error warning. In this example the persona object keys values are all truthy but when I log them into the console undefined is displayed, why?

```js
let persona = {
  generalThings: {
    name: "Fijiwa",
    age: 22,
    birthday: "01.01.2000",
    placeOfBirth: "Tokyo",
    degree: "undefined",
    programLanguage: "JavaScript"
  },

  favouriteThings: {
    musicArtist: "Drake",
    book: "Meditations",
    person: "k",
    fighter: "Nate Diaz"
  },

}

foo = () => {
  for (key in persona) {
    const areTruthy = Object.values(persona[key]).every(value => value);
    console.log(areTruthy === true ? persona[key].value : "please complete the empty fields ");
  }
}
foo();
```

Comment: What do you expect the value of `persona[key].value`?

Comment: I don't see a `value` property anywhere...

Answer (score 2):

The first key is generalThings which is an object, so persona['generalThings'] is equal to

```json
{
    name:"Fijiwa",
    age: 22,
    birthday: "01.01.2000",
    placeOfBirth: "Tokyo",
    degree: "undefined",
    programLanguage: "JavaScript" 
}
```

This object doesnot have a `value` property which means persona['generalThings'].value is undefined.
I guess you want to log persona[key]